# Storage exception in microstream

Tags: java, microstream

I'm using microstream and I try to save my object in storage :

```
EmbeddedStorageFoundation esf = EmbeddedStorageFoundation.New().setConfiguration(storageConfiguration);
storage = esf.createEmbeddedStorageManager();
storage.start();
storage.setRoot(content);
```

when I execute "storage.start()" the exception throw :
[image]
Can you help me what is the problem? If you need another thing comment to provide.

Answer (score 0):

This exception means, that another process is running on the existing storage. It is not allowed.
When you set a root, you need also to save it.

```java
    storageManager.storeRoot();
```